# Why does RDD.foreach fail with "SparkException: This RDD lacks a SparkContext"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a dataset (as an `RDD`) that I divide into 4 RDDs by using different `filter` operators.

```
 val RSet = datasetRdd.
   flatMap(x => RSetForAttr(x, alLevel, hieDict)).
   map(x => (x, 1)).
   reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y)
 val Rp:RDD[(String, Int)] = RSet.filter(x => x._1.split(",")(0).equals("Rp"))
 val Rc:RDD[(String, Int)] = RSet.filter(x => x._1.split(",")(0).equals("Rc"))
 val RpSv:RDD[(String, Int)] = RSet.filter(x => x._1.split(",")(0).equals("RpSv"))
 val RcSv:RDD[(String, Int)] = RSet.filter(x => x._1.split(",")(0).equals("RcSv"))
```

I sent `Rp` and `RpSV` to the following function `calculateEntropy`:

```
def calculateEntropy(Rx: RDD[(String, Int)], RxSv: RDD[(String, Int)]): Map[Int, Map[String, Double]] = {
        RxSv.foreach{item => {
               val string = item._1.split(",")
               val t = Rx.filter(x => x._1.split(",")(2).equals(string(2)))

        .
        .
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1- When I loop operation on `RxSv` as:

```
RxSv.foreach{item=> { ... }}
```

it collects all items of the partitions, but I want to only a partition where i am in. If you said that user `map` function but I don't change anything on `RDD`.

So when I run the code on a cluster with 4 workers and a driver the dataset is divided into 4 partitions and each worker runs the code. But for example i use foreach loop as i specified in the code. Driver collects all data from workers.

2- I have encountered with a problem on this code

```
val t = Rx.filter(x => x._1.split(",")(2).equals(abc(2)))
```

The error :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: This RDD lacks a SparkContext.
```

It could happen in the following cases: 
(1) `RDD` `transformations` and `actions` are NOT invoked by the driver, but inside of other transformations;
 
for example, `rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x)` is invalid because the values `transformation` and `count` `action` cannot be performed inside of the `rdd1.map` `transformation`. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
(2) When a `Spark Streaming` job recovers from checkpoint, this exception will be hit if a reference to an `RDD` not defined by the streaming job is used in `DStream` operations. For more information, See SPARK-13758.

Comment: Can you explain _"but I want to only a partition where i am in"_? What's _"a partition where I'm in"_?

Comment: I have 4 partitions and i want to run code block for each partition without collect all data from partitions

Comment: When you say "partition" you mean the respective RDDs with filtered rows?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I'd highly recommend caching the first RDD using `cache` operator.

```
RSet.cache
```

That will avoid scanning and transforming your dataset every time you `filter` for the other RDDs: `Rp`, `Rc`, `RpSv` and `RcSv`.

Quoting the scaladoc of [cache](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD):

> **cache()** Persist this RDD with the default storage level (MEMORY_ONLY).

Performance should increase.

---

Secondly, I'd be very careful using the term "partition" to refer to a filtered RDD since the term has a special meaning in Spark.

Partitions say how many tasks Spark executes for an action. They are hints for Spark so you, a Spark developer, could fine-tune your distributed pipeline.

The pipeline is distributed across cluster nodes with one or many Spark executors per the partitioning scheme. If you decide to have a one partition in a RDD, once you execute an action on that RDD, you'll have one task on one executor.

The `filter` transformation does not change the number of partitions (in other words, it preserves partitioning). The number of partitions, i.e. the number of tasks, is exactly the number of partitions of `RSet`.

---

> 1- When I loop operation on `RxSv` it collects all items of the partitions, but I want to only a partition where i am in

You are. Don't worry about it as Spark will execute the task on executors where the data lives. `foreach` is an action that does **not** collect items but describes a computation that runs on executors with the data distributed across the cluster (as partitions).

If you want to process all items at once per partition use [foreachPartition](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@foreachPartition(f:Iterator[T]=%3EUnit):Unit):

> **foreachPartition** Applies a function f to each partition of this RDD.

---

> 2- I have encountered with a problem on this code

In the following lines of the code:

```
    RxSv.foreach{item => {
           val string = item._1.split(",")
           val t = Rx.filter(x => x._1.split(",")(2).equals(string(2)))
```

you are executing `foreach` action that in turn uses `Rx` which is `RDD[(String, Int)]`. This is not allowed (and if it were possible should not have been compiled).

The reason for the behaviour is that an RDD is a data structure that just describes what happens with the dataset when an action is executed and lives on the driver (the orchestrator). The driver uses the data structure to track the data sources, transformations and the number of partitions.

A RDD as an entity is gone (= disappears) when the driver spawns tasks on executors.

And when the tasks run nothing is available to help them to know how to run RDDs that are part of their work. And hence the error. Spark is very cautious about it and checks such anomalies before they could cause issues after tasks are executed.

Comment: `val dataset = sc.textFile("Dataset.txt", numberOfPart)` 

I set number of partition as i specified above, I don't mention partition as number of filtered item. Actually, my problem is that my results changes according to the number of worker in my cluster.

Comment: Can you describe _"my problem is that my results changes according to the number of worker in my cluster"_ How do you check the results? What are your expectations? What do you get instead?