# How can I use a RDD filter in another RDD transform

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Now, I need to select add an element in each line in RDD-A. The element comes from the filter operation in the RDD-B.

```
RDD-A.map(line => line.fuctionA(RDD-B,line._1,line._2,line._3))
```

The function-A is to find the line that filtered by the line._1 and line._2 in RDD-B. The following error occurred:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: This RDD lacks a SparkContext.
```

By browsing the problem:[Why does RDD.foreach fail with “SparkException: This RDD lacks a SparkContext”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088088/why-does-rdd-foreach-fail-with-sparkexception-this-rdd-lacks-a-sparkcontext), I knew why it happened.

So, what is the available solution? I've thought that although SPARK does not allow this kind of operation. So how can I achieve this demand？Using the broadcast in SPARK? Or persist the data in HDFS? Is this "filter/query process" enough efficient?

---

RDDs are as follows:

1. RDD-A structure

   ```
   +----------------------+------+------+------+    
   |  some other keys     | var1 | var2 | var3 |    
   +----------------------+------+------+------+    
   +----------------------+------+------+------+
   ```
2. RDD-B structure

   ```
   +--------------------+------+------+------+------+    
   |  the-key-i-want    | var4 | var5 | var6 | var7 |    
   +--------------------+------+------+------+------+    
   +--------------------+------+------+------+------+
   ```

What I want to do is to add an item in each line of RDD-A. The item is the  only queried line in RDD-B. The query requirement is that `var1==var4 && var2==var5 && var3>=var6 && var3<=var7`.

Comment: could you post some example with data. In that way we will get better understanding.

Comment: I have updated the structures of two RDDs. Tell me if the additional notes are not easy to understand.